# Can we simulate an older processor?

Tags: cpu, virtualization

I wish I could emulate an Athlon XP or Pentium IV processor on an third-gen Intel Core. Is there a way to run a virtual machine that specifically *disable* a) newer **cpu features** like `sse2` `sse3`? and b) cpu **cache**?

I'm using Qemu/KVM. The way I launch it only *hides* CPU intructions to the guest OS, whose applications still have access to the host machine's newer ones:

host

```
$ qemu-system-i386 -cpu pentium3,enforce (...) -enable-kvm
```

guest

```
$ inxi -f
CPU:       Single core Pentium III (Katmai) (-UP-) cache: 16384 KB speed: 3292 MHz (max)                
CPU Flags: apic cmov cx8 de fpu fxsr hypervisor mca mce mmx msr mtrr pae pge pse
           pse36 sep sse tsc x2apic

$ firefox   # v.54 which requires sse2;
```

Runs just fine, as do Palemoon and mpv which won't run on a cpu lacking sse2 like the Athlon XP (producing an 'Illegal instruction'). Meaning sse2 is definitively available to the guest OS. Only applications that check the CPUID do fail, e.g.:

```
$ chromium-browser                                                                                                       
# (...)
# Fatal error in ../../v8/src/ia32/assembler-ia32.cc, line 109                                      
# Check failed: cpu.has_sse2().                                                                     
#
#0 0x0000b40b9f0a base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
```

Same thing happens when I run the VM with `-cpu athlon,sse2=off`. So while we can take reasonnable care of e.g. the number of core, the processor speed (using `cpulimit`) or the I/O capabilities (with qemu's [throttle](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/throttle.txt) parameter), we can't limit the cpu instructions set available to the guest, can we?

Comment: If a program uses those extensions that your hiding it means they are required to run those applications

Comment: @Ramhound yeah that's the point. *Disabling* (unlike hiding) them in a vm would allow to detect any application requiring cpu features unsupported on the target cpus. And find alternatives (e.g. sse-only builds). As well as getting an idea of the applications behavior with a limited set of cpu instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to skip usage of KVM and make QEMU emulate all instructions itself in order for the instructions to stop being available.